# EF Code Structure in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, dbset

I need some help with my code structure!

I have a form with some mandatory fields and some optionals.
I run some validation prior to saving the records on the database to make sure the data conforms to integrity rules. If its properly validated the data can then be saved. The problem sets with with my optional fields, comboboxes:

```
private async void SaveRecord()
{
    if (ValidateForm())
    {
        int sucessReg = 0;
        try
        {
            var memberRecord = new ClubMember()
            {// Tab ID
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Surname = txtSurname.Text,
                PassportNumber = (Int32)txtPasspt.text,
                MaritalStatus = cboMarital.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                Gender = cboGender.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                DOB = dtpDob.Value,
                DataEntrada = dtpDataEntra.Value,
                Photo = ConvertImgToBinary(picBoxPhoto.Image),
                Country = cboCountry.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            };

            ctxt.CubMember.Add(memberRecord);
            sucessReg = await ctxt.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (sucessReg == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Record successfully saved.", "System Message");
            }
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            string err;
            err = ex.ToString();
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                err = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(err);
        }
    } 
}
```

Since some comboxes are optional and the selectedValue property is null at the moment of saving, the compiler throws the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
The optional fields should go as is, that is, should be null on the database if the user didn't pick any item on the combo list.

So, I need a better way to structure my code in order to address this issue.
Does anybody have a brilliant idea?? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this method triggered from a c# event?

Comment: You can't call `.ToString` on a null instance. 

You need to check if things like `cboMarital.SelectedValue` are null before you call `ToString` on them.

Comment: Don't get values this way. Data-binding is the way you should go.

Comment: Again  @Reza, I'm new in this EF territory. Could you share some code snippet on this Data-bindings technique? Please don't forget I'm using Winforms not WPF. Thanks.

Comment: It's OK and completely recommended to use data-binding with windows forms controls. In fact if you don't use data binding in windows forms, you have missed one of the best features of the framework. For more information you can see [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Form Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738575(v=vs.100).aspx), [Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx) and [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx). Setting up data binding is supported using both code and designer.

Comment: @Reza, since time its a luxury item I cannot afford to spare right now, I'll go by Mr. Ian's suggestion. I acknowledge that best practices dictates that I should implement Databinding instead of trying to hook my controls manually which is probably  prone to unpredictable errors....but!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `C#6` you could use `?.` null conditional operator to check if `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is `null` before you use `.ToString()`:

```
var memberRecord = new ClubMember()
{// Tab ID
    Name = txtName.Text,
    Surname = txtSurname.Text,
    PassportNumber = (Int32)txtPasspt.text,
    MaritalStatus = cboMarital.SelectedValue?.ToString(),
    Gender = cboGender.SelectedValue?.ToString(),
    DOB = dtpDob.Value,
    DataEntrada = dtpDataEntra.Value,
    Photo = ConvertImgToBinary(picBoxPhoto.Image),
    Country = cboCountry.SelectedValue?.ToString(),
};
```

It is equivalent to:

```
var memberRecord = new ClubMember()
{// Tab ID
    Name = txtName.Text,
    Surname = txtSurname.Text,
    PassportNumber = (Int32)txtPasspt.text,
    MaritalStatus = cboMarital.SelectedValue == null ? null : cboMarital.SelectedValue.ToString(),
    Gender = cboGender.SelectedValue == null ? null : cboGender.SelectedValue.ToString(),
    DOB = dtpDob.Value,
    DataEntrada = dtpDataEntra.Value,
    Photo = ConvertImgToBinary(picBoxPhoto.Image),
    Country = cboCountry.SelectedValue == null ? null : cboCountry.SelectedValue.ToString(),
};
```

Comment: Only the equivalent technique works @Ian, I wonder why...!. Thanks a lot pal, you saved my day.

Comment: @Dhekstro probably you use Visual Studio 2013 or lower... The earlier technique is only for `C#6` (thus VS2015 and above (in the future))